# How to Add a value to an input and if it has value open a div

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to get my head around what is wrong with this bit of code:
 it essentially adds a value of checked onto a radio input and if the radio has that value to  open a div  .

```
$(document).on("click","input[name=newBillingAddress]:radio",function(){
$("input:radio[name=newBillingAddress]:checked").val('checked');
$("input:radio[name=newBillingAddress]:not(:checked)").val('unchecked');
}


if($('#existingBillingRadio').val('checked')){
    $('.toggleBlock').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: You should use the 'prop' method not 'val' for checking checkboxes. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Everywhere in this code, not everywhere in all code. Just when dealing with checkboxes and radios.

Comment: You have an extra `}`, bud. Right smack in the middle.

Comment: Be more precise in your question. What do you means by **that value to open a div**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the value in an if statement you have to compare it

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name=newBillingAddress]:radio", function(){

   $("input:radio[name=newBillingAddress]:checked").val('checked'); 
   $("input:radio[name=newBillingAddress]:not(:checked)").val('unchecked');

    // removed extra }

    if($('#existingBillingRadio').val() === 'checked'){
         $(this).parent().find('.toggleBlock').first().slideDown();
    }

});
```

It's not really clear what you really want but the radio buttons have a ***checked attribute*** and not a *value*. So what you should check is

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name=newBillingAddress]:radio", function(){

   // $("input:radio[name=newBillingAddress]:checked").prop('checked', true);
   // $("input:radio[name=newBillingAddress]:not(:checked)").prop('checked', false);

   // the above lines don't make sense in this case anymore.
   // removed extra }

    if($('#existingBillingRadio').is(':checked')){
         $(this).parent().find('.toggleBlock').first().slideDown();
    }

});
```

Comment: Looking back I could have made the question more clear.. This did what I was looking for. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if($('#existingBillingRadio').val('checked')){
>     $(this).parent().find('.toggleBlock').first().slideDown();
> });
> ```

the above condition is always true and will run only once on page load.

Answer (score -1):

You are making an assignation inside a conditional you must do this:

```
if($('#existingBillingRadio').val() == 'checked')
```

Although I would check only checked property, and remove previous val assignation:

```
if($('#existingBillingRadio')is(":checked") {
    $(this).parent().find('.toggleBlock').first().slideDown();
}
```

Comment: `===`, bro. Also, this is not how you check if a radio input option is selected.